# How to use fitBounds of GMaps.js

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, bounds, gmaps.js

I am using [GMaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-fitBounds) and I have several points to show, I need to show all and set the zoom to the point, I was watching the documentation and requests an array of google.maps.LatLng type. I have the following code

```
for (x in geo){
var item  = new google.maps.LatLng(geo[x]["latitud"], geo[x]["longitud"]);
arrayBound.push(item);
}
map = new GMaps({
div: '#divMapa',
lat: latWS,
lng: lngWS,
zoom: 13
});

map.fitBounds(arrayBound);
```

Comment: The solution is

map.fitLatLngBounds (arrayBound);

The documentation is the fitBounds function but must be fitLatLngBounds and pass as a parameter an array of objects google.maps.LatLng

Answer (score 13):

I didn't find the solution obvious, but, here is an example that works with v0.4.11:

```
var latlngs = [{lat:"39.158542", lng:"-84.423903"}, {lat:"39.4339357", lng:"-84.9850474"}];
var bounds = [];
for (var i in latlngs) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngs[i].lat, latlngs[i].lng);
  bounds.push(latlng);
  map.addMarker({
    lat: latlngs[i].lat,
    lng: latlngs[i].lng
  });
}
map.fitLatLngBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score -1):

Rename `fitBounds` to `fitLatLngBounds`.